# How to check if 2 seekbars have the same value

Tags: android

I have this code. How to check if the first seekbar has the same value with the 2nd seekbar? and viceversa. If I change it check every time if both are the same value

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChangedValue1 = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChangedValue1 = progress;
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(progressChangedValue1));
        }
    });

    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChangedValue2 = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChangedValue2 = progress;

        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            textView2.setText(String.valueOf(progressChangedValue2));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a method lets say

```
// return true when two seekbars progress are equal
boolean seekbarMatches( SeekBar one, SeekBar two){
   return one.getProgress() == two.getProgress();
}
```

now on both `onProgressChanged` call that method  `seekbarMatches(one,two);` and do whatever logic suits you or simply on button click call that method. do not complex things up by having redundant variables whice adds nothing but complexity, the `seekbar` has `getProgress()` which tells you where exactly the seekbar at now.